# What is this utensil for?

Tags: utensils

My sister inherited a bunch of tupperware and plastic utensils. One of them, we couldn't understand its purpose.

[image] [image]
<sup>Click for full size</sup>
Ideas so far is to keep pizza-box lid from falling, or to measure equidistance for slices in a cake. **What is the name and purpose of this utensil?**

Comment: Hi everybody, I would like to remind you that comments are for clarification, not for answering. If you have a guess, please write it into an answer. "I don't know for certain, it's just a guess" is not a reason to write it into a comment - please post it either as an answer, or not at all.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

My google-fu powers tell me that yes, it's indeed a [mini cake divider](https://www.thetupperwarelady.co.uk/products/mini-cake-divider?variant=26426484871).

You put it on top of the cake and slice through the slits to get uniformly sized cake slices.

[image]

Comment: Ha! I assumed it was a food holder/finger protector for a mandolin slicer. Good answer.

Comment: @rumtscho - I write this with all due respect and appreciation for your work and balanced moderation, but is it the best idea to chastise users for extraneous commenting and then post a digressive comment on the same question? While your comment is interesting (in a broad sense), it doesn't help answer the question, nor does offer information or a constructive suggestion to improve the answer. It is, frankly, off-topic and indirectly critical of the device OP asked about. Normally, I wouldn't care, but I'm not sure it's helpful to send mixed messages about comments on the same post.

Comment: @athanasius point taken, thank you for speaking up

Comment: @PoloHoleSet my first guess just by looking at the photo was the same, but then I read the question and I thought the cake thing made sense - although I never saw one before. TIL.

Comment: I'm guessing that the utensil can be turned upside down for ring-shape cakes as well!